# What is the propper way to handle certain CRUD exceptions in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model, constraints

I have these models.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['account', 'brand', 'name']
```

So sometimes a name for the same brand and account might be repeaten. Should I handle these constraint exceptions in views, in forms? What is the more clean way to do it? Django is really versatile and you can do things in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

For clean way, create form as **ModelForm**. **ModelForm** supports handling the uniqueness of the model field. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

In case using **Form** class, handle the the uniqueness exception with clean() function.